# What happens when glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf in AWS glue ETL job returns an error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

Let say I have cataloged my files from s3 bucket and while inserting the records in my RDS error occurs because of primary key violation or some other reason, will my ETL job will stop processing?

How would I know that error has occurred?
How would I reprocess those records if needed?
How would I know data from which files are processed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing the df to RDS and any error occurred then all the records will be rolled back and no data will be written to your table and you will receive the error on console.

Comment: But how do i know that the failed records belong to which files and how can I re-process it ?

Comment: You will get the error which will lead you to the malformed record

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue has the concept of [Job Bookmarks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html), that help track processed records based on timestamps of the files in the source bucket/s in s3. Only new files will be processed. In your job, make sure you have the [`transformation-ctx`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html#monitor-continuations-implement-context) and at the end of your job also make sure you have `job.commit()`. These are also well documented in the link I shared above. You can support data backfilling scenarios better by rewinding your job bookmarks to any previous job run, resulting in the subsequent job run reprocessing data only from the bookmarked job run.

In ETL, my advice is to add some timestamp column for each write. For example adding a `etl_batch_insert_date`. This will help you easily rewind bookmarks and drop the records that match the partially failed inserts for example.